# Error creating Visual Studio 2022 preview network installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, maui

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio 2022 preview network installer to reuse the installation media between multiple computers.
I'm following the instructions from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), but I'm downloading the preview installer from [the VS preview page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/#download-preview).
When I try to create the network installer from an elevated command prompt with

```
vs_community.exe --layout D:\VS\Community2022preview --useLatestInstaller
```

I'm getting the error message

```
Download of 'https://aka.ms/vs/17/pre/channel' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
Download of 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/b3f0a1e5-a37b-49a5-9c42-8724caed1f7b/b6c95d2cc95b704820db1e1355cfb2d1d075a8acf8e38b1ddaf1dafedb269521/VisualStudioPreview.vsman' succeeded using engine 'WebClient'
Catalog load operation correlation: {"id":"2d2ff4dd-dc49-49c9-94c7-35b8d0e072a6"}
Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.UpdateRequiredException' was thrown.
Error: Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.UpdateRequiredException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.CheckForEngineUpdate(Version manifestEngineVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Load(String path, Boolean skipVerify)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Layout.Commands.LayoutCommand.InvokeCommand(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Layout.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I googled Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.UpdateRequiredException, but I didn't find anything.
Should this work for the VS 2022 community preview version?
Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: After removing the --useLatestInstaller parameter is working, I will ask MS for more information.

Comment: For my particular use case, the final command used to generate the network installer was

`vs_community --layout d:\vs\preview --lang en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal --includeRecommended --includeOptional`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message with Visual Studio Professional 17.3.0. I followed [Rodrigo Juarez's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170497/rodrigo-juarez) suggestion of removing `--useLatestInstaller` and that solved the problem so that seems to be the solution to this particular error.